# Turn off Zurb Foundation 5 meta tags

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Searched all over the internet but could not find anything about it.
How can I turn off this zurb foundation 5 meta tags in `<head>`:

```
<meta class="foundation-mq-small">
<meta class="foundation-mq-small-only">
<meta class="foundation-mq-medium">
<meta class="foundation-mq-medium-only">
<meta class="foundation-mq-large">
<meta class="foundation-mq-large-only">
<meta class="foundation-mq-xlarge">
<meta class="foundation-mq-xlarge-only">
<meta class="foundation-mq-xxlarge">
<meta class="foundation-data-attribute-namespace">
```

Comment: The `foundation-mq-` meta tags are generated by Foundation JS to be used in various plugins (interchange, topbar, tooltip, etc.). They're important if you wish to retain the functionality that some of those modules provide.

Comment: I just want to use a Reveal Modal as a standalone plugin, that's why I need to include a `foundation.js` file.

Comment: if you have jQuery enabled, just remove them using $('meta[class*="foundation"]').remove();

Comment: These meta tags generate html validation errors on https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You shouldn't. They are needed for some Foundation's JS plugins.

2) If you want to just use Reveal Modal, you don't need removing these meta tags. You can simply include only this plugin into your webstie:

```
<script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
```

Or, if you are using `foundation.min.js`, you can init only this plugin:

```
$(document).foundation('reveal');
```

3) If you are absolutely confident you want to remove these tags for some reason, you have three possibilities:

**Editation of file `foundation.js`**

Remove this part from the file `foundation.js`.

```
header_helpers([
   'foundation-mq-small',
   'foundation-mq-small-only',
   'foundation-mq-medium',
   'foundation-mq-medium-only',
   'foundation-mq-large',
   'foundation-mq-large-only',
   'foundation-mq-xlarge',
   'foundation-mq-xlarge-only',
   'foundation-mq-xxlarge',
   'foundation-data-attribute-namespace']);
```

**Removal by plain JavaScript (after include)**

Include thit code snippet somwhere into your website. It should be run after Foundation initialization.

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (index = metas.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
  var metaClass = metas[index].getAttribute('class') || '';
  if (metaClass.indexOf('foundation') > -1) {
    metas[index].parentNode.removeChild(metas[index]);
  }
}
```

**Removal by jQuery (after include)**

This code snippet needs jQuery, however, you should have it included already because Foundation depends on it. And, of course, it should be also run after Foundation initialization.

```
$('meta[class*=\'foundation\']').remove();
```